# Numbers and its properties

Tags: number-theory

Find the last two digits of 3 to the power 2010.
I tried using the method of obtaining last digit.I could obtain only the last digit of this number. I want to know the method of finding the second last digit of this number. Please provide me the solution to this question.

Comment: Have you written down the first 10 to 20 terms of $3^n$ to look for patterns? What have you discovered?

Answer (score 1):

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, to compute $3^{2010} \pmod{100}$, it is sufficient to compute $3^{2010}\pmod{4}$ and $3^{2010}\pmod{25}$.

Listing the first few powers of $3$ modulo $4$ will show you the pattern, and give you $3^{2010}\pmod{4}$.

The first few powers of $3$ modulo $25$ are $1,3,9,2,6,18,4,12,11,8,24, \ldots$

So, $3^{10} \equiv 24 \pmod{25}$. What does this tell you about $3^{2010}\pmod{25}$?

From here, you can compute $3^{2010} \pmod{100}$, and thus, get the last 2 digits of $3^{2010}$.

Answer (score 0):

I have just written out the powers of 3 and their second digits. I found that it cycles every 24 powers starting from power of 0 it goes:
0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 4, 2, 8, 6, 8, 4, 4, 4, 2, 6, 0, 2, 6, 8, 0, 2, 6, 8, 6.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\phi(100)=40$, where $\phi$ is the totienr function. By Euler's Theorem,

$$3^{40} \equiv 1 \pmod {100}$$

Now, notice that $2010 = 40 \times 50 +10$.